# Delete files older than 182.5 days [deletes newly copied files from years ago]

Tags: python, powershell

I made a routine that runs everyday at 06:00. The routine checks the files' age and if older than 182.5 days, the file will be deleted. A co-worker of mine made a script that would transfer zip files and unpack them in the folder that the routine focuses on. The problem is that when un-zipping, the file age will retain the original age, which is older than 182.5 days.

Is there a way to change the age of the copied files, so that when files are copied in, they automatically change the age of the files copied?

Comment: you can use the `Get-Item` cmdlet to get the file info for a file - and it will be _live_. [*grin*] so you can use that to set the timestamp to what you want.

Comment: The problem may be the difference between date _modified_ and date _created_. Just because you copied files from one place to another does not mean they have a new modified date, but they do have a new creation date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can touch the files.

```
from pathlib import Path
Path('thefile.txt').touch()
```